# Downloading Folder Structures with Apache commons net ftp

Tags: android, ftp, apache-commons-net

I found [apache-commons ftp retrieve multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452987/apache-commons-ftp-retrieve-multiple-files?rq=1) - is there a way to download the complete folder structure in a given start directory from the ftp server?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar with [apache common ftpclient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net//apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)

 it provides you with a single file download , a file info, a directory listing, you need to implement your own logic to traverse over subfiles and folder , decide whether subfile is a file or folder, add files to a download queue, and create the directory hierarchy, then start downloading from the queue. and you're done!

 After that if you had issues, post your effort and SO members including me will be glad to help you :)